# Miminum of each list in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I was wondering if it was possible to get the minimum value of each list in a list of lists.

```
import csv
data=[]
file=input ("Enter file name: ")
with open(file,"r") as f:
      reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
      for row in reader:
      data.append(row)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[['13.25', '12.97', '13.12', '13.47', '13.44', '13.09', '12.86', '12.78', '12.91', '12.93', '12.91', '13.11'], ['12.92', '13.42', '13.58', '13.7', '13.62', '13.7', '13.31', '12.86', '12.59', '12.81', '13.46', '12.9'], ['13.39', '13.5', '13.29', '13.26', '13.38', '13.45', '13.46', '11.95', '', '12.57', '13.22', '12.88'], ['12.48', '13.76', '13.7', '13.77', '13.08', '13.48', '13.25', '12.31', '12.56', '12.56', '12.95', '13.38'], ['12.52', '14.07', '14.46', '14.13', '13.98', '14.07', '13.92', '12.7', '13.01', '12.79', '13', '13.13']]
```

Comment: Plesae indent your code correctly.

Comment: Your loading code is not very illustrative of your actual problem. Include the output of that final statement, or a representative subset thereof, instead.

Comment: @LutzHorn Sorry I'm still getting used to posting on here.

Comment: @unwind I added the output.

Comment: Do you want to interpret the data as numbers?

Comment: @Lutz Horn I have done later in the code.

Comment: @Tetra you should cast the strings to numbers *before* finding the minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has a min function that can be called on lists to get the lowest value.  You can loop through your `data` list and call `min()` on each list contained.

```
for list in data:
    print(min(list))
```

Given your output this would return:

```
12.78
12.59

12.31
12.52
```

The third one is blank because the array has an empty value in it.

---

If you want to remove empty strings you can use `filter()`

```
for list in data:
    list = filter(None, list)
    print(min(list))
```

This outputs

```
12.78
12.59
11.95
12.31
12.52
```

Also I noticed all the values are floats, you can also convert them before checking min value so you're not comparing strings.

```
for list in data:
    list = filter(None, list)
    list = [float(i) for i in list]
    print(min(list))
```

Comment: Is there an exception that avoids the blank?

Comment: @Tetra Absolutely.  Can simply filter before we check for min.  I edited my answer with an example.

Answer (score 3):

The minimum value of a *list of lists of numbers* can be achieved with a simple call to [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
numbers = [[1,3,6], [6,7,2], [0,-4]]
minimum_numbers = map(min, numbers)
print minimum_numbers
# This prints: [1, 2, -4]
```

This will return a list where [`min`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) was called for each element in the "outer list" `numbers`.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to convert each of the items to floats. Do this when you read the data in:

```
import csv
data=[]
file=input ("Enter file name: ")
with open(file,"r") as f:
      reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
      for row in reader:
          data.append([float(x) for x in row if x]) # converts values to floats, ignores empty ones
print(data)
```

Once your done with that, just call `min()` on each list:

```
>>> [min(x) for x in data]
[12.78, 12.59, 11.95, 12.31, 12.52]
```

You can shorten your reading loop to this:

```
>>> with open(file, "r") as f:
...    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
...    data = [[float(x) for x in row] for row in reader]

>>> print([min(x) for x in data])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use [Emil Vikström's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24570675/1149736), but since you have control over your loading code you can prevent unnecessary storing of data and simply do:

```
with open(file,"r") as f:
      reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
      for row in reader:
          data.append(min(map(float, row)))
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use the map function...

```
listOfLists = [ [2, 3, 1], [5, 7, 8], .... ]

minValues = map(lambda x: min(x), listOfLists)

Result:
minValues = [1, 5, ...]
```